# Awk: How to loop through a file to get every line?

Tags: awk

I have a file with information in it:

```
Name   Rate   Hours



Clark  8.5    42
Sarah  18.5   19 
Joe    10     25
Paul   12     5
```

I want to calculate the total pay for **each** employee.

But I cannot get my loop to work because I am unsure of what `i <=` should be due to the headers (`Name`, `Rate`, `Hours`) in the beginning of the file.

So far I have this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    total = 0;
}

{
    rate = $2;
    hours = $3;
        for (i = 1; i<= NR; i++)
    {
            total = rate * hours;
    }
}

END {
    print "Total = $" total;
}' testfile.dat
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative,something like this works ok and has a nice output:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{$4="total"}NR>1{$4=$2*$3}1' testfile.dat
#Output:
Name    Rate    Hours   total
Clark   8.5       42    357
Sarah   18.5      19    351.5
Joe     10        25    250
Paul    12         5    60
```

Comment: How do I make this work for BEGIN and END, and not just the command line?

Comment: @user455555009 You don't need BEGIN and END to be always present in awk. If you advise what is the expected output based on your input file, i can elaborate my answer.

Comment: No need to, you have been extremely helpful, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Awk puts an implicit loop around the bulk of the script: apart from the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks (and function definitions), the script runs for every line in sequence. So it would be very strange to have a loop like `for (i = 1; i<= NR; i++)` in an awk script: when awk goes through the first line this executes the loop body for `i=1`, then awk goes through the second line and the loop body is executed for `i=1` and `i=2`, then awk goes through the second line and the loop body is executed for `i=1` and `i=2` and `i=3`, etc.

Assuming that employee names are not repeated, the total pay for each employee is simply `$2 * $3`. You can print that out if you want:

```
NR == 1 { print $1, $2, $3, "total" }
NR != 1 { print $1, $2, $3, $2 * $3 }
```

(The condition `NR == 1` identifies the header line.)

The total pay for all the employees is the sum of this expression for every line apart from the header line. To calculate the total pay for all the employees, add the current employee's pay to the running total.

```
NR != 1 { total += $2 * $3 }
```

Comment: `for (i = 1; i<= NR; i++) loops over the fields on each line`  is not entirely correct. `i<=NF`

Comment: @RakeshSharma Oops, you're right, I'd misread that, thanks.

Comment: You have a typo in `NR != 1 { print $1, $2, $3, $2 * $4 }` - Should be $2*$3 in the end.